# What do you call a thing that holds a heavy armor?

Tags: word-request

https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Power_armor_station_(Fallout_4)

In Fallout 4, they use the term "power armor station", but I am wondering if there's any other word for these type of support object that holds a heavy armor in place.

[image]

This weird contraption doesn't seem to have a name in English. The armor is hung by the contraption.

Comment: Is this the same question as [What do you call the thing that holds Iron Man's suits?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223259/what-do-you-call-the-thing-that-holds-iron-mans-suits) Armor is kept on a [**stand**](https://www.pinterest.co.uk/davis4586/armor-stands/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call the thing that holds Iron Man's suits?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/223259/what-do-you-call-the-thing-that-holds-iron-mans-suits)

Comment: I don’t believe this is a duplicate, because Iron Man’s suits can stand (and actually function as drones) on their own. The Fallout device suspends the armor instead of just displaying it, as in this picture http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/fallout/images/9/93/Fo4_T45d_power_armor_trailer.png/revision/latest?cb=20150604184602

Comment: That is the same idea as a man's suit stand. Stand would be the word in English.

Comment: BTW, "armor" is not a countable noun. You can have "holds armor", "holds some armor", "holds a piece of armor", "holds a suit of armor", but not "holds an armor".

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn’t a specific word for an “armor holder” because we don’t have heavy suits of armor that need to be suspended that way. We do have other heavy things that we suspend to work on, like engines, or use a device to help move around because they’re heavy, like large animals.

I think the term “[lift](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lift)” (*A machine or device designed to pick up, raise, or carry something.*) or even “armor lift” would apply. For example, this is a “truck lift”:

[image: A truck on a lift with a man working on it from underneath]

Lifts make heavy things easier to work on by suspending them at convenient heights. I’m not sure it completely captures the device in fallout, because I don’t think we typically store things on lifts.

Answer (score 1):

Going only by common usage I've been exposed to in real world military settings, it seems to depend on the purpose of the thing doing the holding...

- ... when it is being used to display the item, it's called a "stand"
- ... when it's used to hold an item securely in position, it's called
  a "rack"
- ... when it's used to manipulate an item for performing
  maintenance or supply, it's called a "lift" or a "dock"

So in the Fallout setting, it could generically be called a rack. Most players seem to call them stands, and lift or dock would still be acceptable.

Of course the game calls them stations, so technically that's the right answer regardless.